# Printing sqlite database information as soon as user enters the input

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm trying to use python to do an sqlite query and I'm facing a problem with sqlite.
I want to fetch information from database as soon as user inputs data.for example I'm having 2 files a.py and b.py,a.py runs infinitely inorder to display the information everytime when user inputs, and b.py is used add details to the database so once when the user enters the details to database a.py gets invoke and  it will print the details.So I tried to implement this but it only works for the first iteration only (like when I add details in b.py,a.py gets invoked and prints the details)  then for the second  iteration I'm getting an operational error saying database locked.

Comment: And now you want to know what "database locked" means?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.